# Download my files on Dropbox with only app key/secret?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to download files for my private app without having to go through oauth.

In other word, I want to simplify the process to get my files from remote dropbox. Preferable, something like invoking GET to `/files/<path>?key=<APP_KEY>` to download the file at `<path>`.

Is it possible to accomplish that on Dropbox API?

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API does not offer the ability to download files from an account without authorization. You'll need an access token to use [/2/files/download](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download). Access tokens don't expire by themselves though, so you can store and re-use them without further manual user intervention. I.e., get an access token for your account manually once, and just store that so your app can use it to call [/2/files/download](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download) as documented each time.

Alternatively, if you only need to download from pre-determined file(s), you can get shared link(s) for the file(s) and download directly from the shared link(s):

- https://www.dropbox.com/help/files-folders/view-only-access
- https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/force-download